# Can not find local variable 'pos' in a method arguments android

Tags: java, android

```
CallUploadService(msg, position);
```

This is the method I am calling from `getView()` and passing current position to the method and `msg` is a reference of a model contains some properties

```
private void CallUploadService(final MessageModel msg, final int pos) 
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

Here I have defined my method `CallUploadService` when I debug it says can not find local variable `pos`.I don't know what is the reason any help please

Comment: make you `position` variable as final  in your `getView()` method

Comment: Provide a running example and more code and there might be a possibility for us to help you. What you have written so far can just lead to various assumptions

Comment: Variable position is already final in getView() method still have same problem

Comment: Basically, after getting position  in CallUploadService() method I am doing this 
View view = (View) ((ChatActivity) context).Lv_Chat.getItemAtPosition(pos);
  final ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
  final TextView size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLength);

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Please Help others to reproduce the problem

Comment: How? I mean did I ask a question in a wrong way?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed any error in the logcat you could add to your post ? Is the error happens when you build the app or at runtime ? (BTW you can edit your post)

Comment: No, there is no error in log cat but it goes to exception clause and second thing how can I edit my post please tell me then I will be able to show my complete code thanks